# What user accounts should I use when installing SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Web edition to our webserver. During Installation, I am asked to configure service accounts for different types of services. The installer also mentions that I should use different accounts for each service.

Here's a screenshot of the installer window:

http://screencast.com/t/NWRlY2U4OTg

What user accounts should I enter for the SQL Server Agent, Database Engine and Analysis Service services? The manual just mentions that there is no default account for these.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to create at least one Windows user to run the services under.  The account can be either a local account or a domain account.

You can create one account for each service, or just create one account for all services to run under.  One account for each service is the most secure technique, however one account for all services is the most common configuration.

After you create the account(s) do not add it(them) to the administrators group or any other group than Users.  The installer will give the accounts the needed rights.

Comment: All I needed to know in just 3 paragraphs. I wonder why MS can't write this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: They've got a nice 60-80 page white paper somewhere that spells it out.  If you don't fall asleep or die of old age while reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use seperate accounts for each service if you do not want to.

Here is a guide from Microsoft on how to create more service accounts though:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx